# Why is my program not detecting uppercase characters?

Tags: python, string, uppercase

I am asking the user to input a password. The program then determines if the password is valid if it meets certain criteria.

Here is the section in question.

```
for i in range(0, len(password)):
    if(password[i].isdigit()==True):
        isNum+=1
    elif (password[i].isalpha()==True):
        isLetter+=1
    elif (password[i].isupper()==True):
        isUpper+=1
```

My program detects numbers and letters just fine, but it doesn't detect uppercase letters. If I put in the password 1234Foxes, it will say that there are 4 letters, 4 numbers, and 8 total characters, but it states that there are 0 uppercase letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `isupper` is true, `isalpha` must have been true since an uppercase letter is necessarily alphabetic. Since you're using `elif`, the conditions are exclusive, and the checks stop once the `isalpha` check is true.

Just don't use `elif` there if you want both checks to run:

```
for character in password:
    if(character.isdigit()):
        isNum += 1

    elif (character.isalpha()):
        isLetter += 1

        if (character.isupper()):
            isUpper += 1
```

I also got rid of the need to index `password` by iterating the String directly, and the redundant `== True`

Comment: The second conditional can be an elif. The third should be nested within it

Comment: @MadPhysicist Good call. Figured the performance wouldn't matter, but it is more correct.

Answer (score 0):

your logic is correct, but, you need to check if a char is upper before if it is alpha. It's because every upper char is alpha, so, the last elif will never be reached. So, change your code position to this:

```
for i in range(0, len(password)):
   if(password[i].isdigit()==True):
       isNum+=1
   # isupper() first from isalpha()
   elif (password[i].isupper()==True):
       isUpper+=1
   elif (password[i].isalpha()==True):
       isLetter+=1
```

And, another tip: you can go through every char of string without using indexing, like this:

```
for char in password:
   if (char.isdigit()):
       isNum += 1
   elif (char.isupper()):
       isUpper += 1
   elif (char.isalpha()):
       isLetter += 1
```

Since isdigit(), isalpha() and isupper() returns True or False, you don't need to check if it is True or False (no need the == operator), just put it into if statement.